# Three.js Some objects not seen through pointCloudMaterial texture with transparency

Tags: three.js, textures, transparency, particles

Im trying to move particles (THREE.PointCloud) accross thre scene.  This particles are composed by this material with transparent png.

```
var material = new     THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { 
        size: tamanio,
        color:color, 
        //alphaTest:0.01,
        transparent:true,
        depthTest:true,
        map:recursoConNombre("textura_particula").objeto,
        blending:THREE.AdditiveBlending         
    });
```

All seems Ok, but some objects not seen through the transparent texture of the particle.  [Image of the problem, particles with transparent textsure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hacph.jpg)  The three particles with the red circle are in the same PointCloud object, some objects are not seen through the texture (the right two are wrong).

EDIT: I created a Fiddle to reproduce the problem, some spheres not seen through some transparent particles: http://jsfiddle.net/g68jbsoy/1/ (Mouse click to create a particle explosion)

Comment: Can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/) and create a live example?

Comment: fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/g68jbsoy/
(Mouse click to create a particle explosion)

Comment: 1. Your spheres are transparent. Is that a requirement? In three.js, transparent objects are rendered last -- opaque ones first. 2. Can you make a static example. It is too hard to know what you are not happy with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the transparency of your point cloud, and the points being rendered in the incorrect order.

When rendering transparent objects, they need to rendered 'front to back'. Meaning the objects further away need to rendered first, and the closest object last.

Originally the PointCloud object had a sortParticles property to help do this for you, but it has been removed.

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5668